# How do I get rid of lag while using transform on scroll event?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, css-animations, css-transforms

So I'm trying to add a smooth scrolling effect for a site that I'm working on. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/khalidahmedfazal/40xfeg17/11/) is the link to the fiddle of the problem I'm trying to solve.

What I'm doing here is watching the scroll event and translating the `#smooth-content` div by the amount scrolled. I get the intended effect but there's a lag from the time I scroll to the time the div is translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lag is caused by the timing function of the transition.
You're using a cubic-bezier for that.

you could try a bezier with a steeper start:
IE: `cubic-bezier(0,.79,.65,.99)`

A [helpful tool](https://cubic-bezier.com/#0,.79,.65,.99) can be used  find a bezier that fits your needs.
In general the steeper the graph, the faster your animation will be.
You can even 'overshoot' and have it bounce back.

```js
let yOffset = 0;

const handleScroll = () => {
  scrollSmoothly();

  yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
}

const scrollSmoothly = () => {
  var scrollAmount = yOffset * -1;

  $("#smooth-content").css({
    transform: `translate3d(0, ${scrollAmount}px, 0)`
  });
}

$(document).on('touchmove', handleScroll);
$(document).on('scroll', handleScroll);
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
}

#smooth-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#smooth-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  will-change: transform;
  transition: 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, .79, .65, .99);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="smooth-wrapper">
  <div id="smooth-content">
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
    <p>
      <!-- It is a Paragraph tag for creating the paragraph -->
      <b> HTML </b> stands for <i> <u> Hyper Text Markup Language. </u> </i> It is used to create a web pages and applications. This language is easily understandable by the user and also be modifiable. It is actually a Markup language, hence it provides
      a flexible way for designing the web pages along with the text.
    </p>
    HTML file is made up of different elements. <b> An element </b> is a collection of <i> start tag, end tag, attributes and the text between them</i>.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent hours trying to figure out what was up. Guess I just didn't quite understand how cubic-bezier works.